# Android Google Maps OutOfMemory

Tags: android, google-maps, out-of-memory, android-mapview

I'm using MapView + Google Maps API in application. It's work but sometime has problem with memory. I tried add

> largeHeap = true

in

> AndroidManifest.xml

But the problem remains unresolved.

TrackLog :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with 1810320 free bytes and 1767KB until OOM
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Bitmap.java)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:977)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.k.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:7)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:73)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:46)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.ah.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:39)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ae.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:59)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.am.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:346)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:407)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:664)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:270)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.f(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:257)
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bb.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11746440:11)
```

In my fragment :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mMapView != null) {
        mMapView.onResume();
        mLocationHelper.checkPlayServices();
    }
}


 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if (mMapView != null && mGoogleMap != null) {
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
            mGoogleMap.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            mGoogleMap.clear();
        }
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onDestroy();
            mMapView = null;
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

Libraries :

- play-services-maps:11.4.0
- play-services-location:11.4.0

Thanks !

Comment: Interesting enough I do get that too with: The EXACT same number of bytes in an app.  "Failed to allocate a 4194316 byte allocation with...". I seems to only appear on Android 6-devices. (Almost the same line numbers in the stack trace so I assume it is a "nearby" version of libraries.)

Comment: Seems to be related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823043

Answer (score 0):

What `largeheap=true` does is, it enhances the size of RAM given to your app. For example, if your android gives 1MB RAM size per app, enabling large heap gives 2MB instead. Thus, this can resolve Out of Memory issue only when the memory you are using is now under the new given large spec of RAM. Which is why people say `largeheap=true` is not the best way to fix OOM since it only delays OOM from happening, so it is recommended to fix OOM without `largeheap=true` most of the time.

I am not sure from your given code which container you are using, but REFRESHING your container so that it releases the excessive amount of used memory to be able to be recycled by the garbage collector, is one typical way to fix OOM. First, try manually refreshing the container(exit and enter maybe) to see if it resolves OOM. In the end, you will have to program your container to automatically be refreshed to prevent OOM.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I did clear MapView and Google Maps when destroy view. Can you give me some solutions ?

Comment: When do you experience OOM specifically?